# Catch edit event on slightly modified CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, ckeditor

I'm writing simple editing panel, where I've got few CKEditor windows where i need to catch some kind of edit event.

Before changes, this code was doing it perfectly:

```
$('.cke_wysiwyg_frame').on('load', function(){ console.log('hi') });
```

but for design issues, I've made .cke-bottom and .cke-top invisible by css

```
 .cke_bottom, .cke_top{ display: none; }
```

After that, I tried many ways to catch the edit event, examples:

```
 $(CKEDITOR.instances.desc_product).click(function() { console.log('hi'); });
 $("[id^=cke_").click(function(){ console.log('hi'); });
```

but none of them has worked as good as previous. Is there any way to do it with top and bottom bar hidden?

Comment: show use html code

Comment: whole generated code? It's quite big even for single instance of editor

Comment: only the elements with .cke-bottom and .cke-top classes

Comment: here you go... but still it's a very big
https://pastebin.com/JMBjz1j4